# NeutralResourcesLanguage Usage

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, silverlight, resources

The verbiage below is from a generated AssemblyInfo file. Does this mean MS is recommending I modify the .csproj file by hand? By a Setting?

If it is by a Setting then what use is the NeutralResourcesLanguage attribute? How are you supposed to access it in code.

Cheers,
Berryl

```
//In order to begin building localizable applications, set 
//<UICulture>CultureYouAreCodingWith</UICulture> in your .csproj file
//inside a <PropertyGroup>.  For example, if you are using US english
//in your source files, set the <UICulture> to en-US.  Then uncomment
//the NeutralResourceLanguage attribute below.  Update the "en-US" in
//the line below to match the UICulture setting in the project file.

//[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This attribute (not a setting) can be defined in project properties, like so

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click your project, and then Click Properties.
2. From the left navigation bar select Application, and then click Assembly Information.
3. In the Assembly Information dialog box, select the language from the Neutral Language drop-down list.
4. Click OK.

Comment: Thanks, But VS Express doesn't add **, UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite**. So you must open AssemblyInfo.cs and manually add the highlighted text

Answer (score 8):

In **.Net core** projects you can specify it in `csproj`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  <NeutralLanguage>fr</NeutralLanguage>
</PropertyGroup>
```

or using `Visual studio`:

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click your project, and then Click `Properties`.
2. From the left navigation bar select `Package`
3. Select value for `Assembly neutral language`

Answer (score 0):

Drop this into your csproj file within the project:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Resources.NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute">
        <_Parameter1>"en-US"</_Parameter1>
        <_Parameter1_IsLiteral>true</_Parameter1_IsLiteral>
        <_Parameter2>System.Resources.UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite</_Parameter2>
        <_Parameter2_IsLiteral>true</_Parameter2_IsLiteral>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).